# Centering contents after \unvbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tex-core, boxes

Trying to build a complex macro, I managed to compute what I need in a vbox.
Now, I want to `\unvbox` this box to allow page breaks, and would like each element it contains to be centered.

I can't find a way to add some glue on the left and right of each element. Is it at all possible? Any alternative?

Edit: typical boxes I'd like to handle are of this kind:

```
\vbox{
  \halign{\hfil#&\hfil#\hfil&#\hfil\cr
  aa & b & cc\cr
  d & eee & f\cr}
}
```

(I don't really want to modify them because I need to access their `\wd` at some point).

Comment: It all depends on how the `\vbox` has been built. Can you provide some code?

Comment: Added some some typical example. In practice, the contents `aa`, `b`… are other big boxes.

Comment: Can you provide a full minimal example? What do you want to reach?

Comment: The `\halign` is formed, at its outer level, by hboxes all of the same width. It's not clear what you want to achieve. What do you want to center?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## First method

This code is Plain TeX, but can be used also in LaTeX; the macro `\centervbox` takes as argument a box register number and outputs the same box, but centered with respect to the margins.

```
\catcode`\@=11
\def\centervbox#1{\begingroup\global\setbox\@ne=\box\voidb@x
  \setbox\z@=\copy#1\relax\docentervbox}
\def\docentervbox{%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{\unvbox\z@ \setbox\tw@=\lastbox
    \skip@=\lastskip\unskip
    \global\setbox\@ne=\vbox{
      \vskip\skip@
      \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\tw@\hfil}
      \unvbox\@ne}}%
  \ifdim\ht\z@=\z@
    \def\next{\unvbox\@ne\endgroup}%
  \else
    \let\next\docentervbox
  \fi
  \next}
\catcode`\@=12

\vsize=5\baselineskip

\setbox4=\vbox{
  \halign{\hfil#&\hfil#\hfil&#\hfil\cr
  aa & b & cc\cr
  aa & b & cc\cr
  aa & b & cc\cr
  aa & b & cc\cr
  aa & b & cc\cr
  aa & b & cc\cr
  d & eee & f\cr}
}

\centervbox{4}

\bye
```

In the example I've used box register 4, but if you say `\newbox\mybox` and then

```
\setbox\mybox=\vbox{...}
```

then you can say `\centervbox\mybox`. The box register remains untouched (if it's not box register 1, but using this would be *a very bad thing*).

**Comments to the first method**
We assume that there is already a box built as a `\vbox` in a box register, that is something like `\setbox\mybox=\vbox{...}` and that this box contains only hboxes and glue between them. The procedure is to copy this box into a scratch box (number 0); we reserve also box register 1, on which we'll act always globally, first of all ensuring it's void. Then we start the recursion: at each step we retrieve the bottom hbox from box 0 and transfer it into box 1; we also transfer the interline glue. However, the retrieved box is put inside a box as wide as `\hsize` and centered in it.

The recursion ends when the height of box 0 is zero. At that point we `\unvbox` box register 1.

## Second method

An alternative way to do the same is to typeset twice the alignment, first gathering its natural width and then with the desired preamble:

```
\newdimen\alignlen \newtoks\preamble
\long\def\centeralign#1#2{\par\preamble{#1}%
  \setbox0=\vbox{\tabskip=0pt\halign{&##\cr#2\crcr}}%
  \alignlen=\wd0
  \begingroup\tabskip=0pt plus 1fil
  \halign to\hsize{\tabskip=0pt \the\preamble\tabskip=0pt plus 1fil\cr
    #2\crcr}\endgroup}

\bigskip

\centeralign{\hfil#&\hfil#\hfil&#\hfil}
 {aa & b & cc\cr
  aa & b & cc\cr
  aa & b & cc\cr
  aa & b & cc\cr
  aa & b & cc\cr
  aa & b & cc\cr
  d & eee & f\cr}
```

This requires a slightly different syntax, but not so complicated. First the alignment is typeset in a box with a standard preamble, nothing more than "print each entry". The length register `\alignlen` is loaded with the width. Then the alignment is typeset with infinite glue on each side, with the desired preamble. Since the `\halign` is outside any box, it can be split across pages. This method has the advantage that `\noalign` commands can be put after `\cr`, stating penalties and vertical skips.

**Comments to the second method**
If the box to center is an `\halign` we can use a different method. First of all we typeset the `\halign` inside a box with a trivial preamble `&#\cr` means "any number of columns with left alignment"; this will give the possibility to measure the natural width of the alignment, as requested.

Then we typeset the alignment with the requested preamble, but with infinitely stretchable `\tabskip` glue at both sides. The preamble had been saved in the token register `\preamble`, we simply augment it by adding `\tabskip=0pt` which will hold for all intercolumn spacing, at the start and the infinite glue specification for the spacing at the right.

## Third method

It's possible to carry in the newly formed box also kerns and penalties, in addition to skips and boxes. No other items can come along.

```
\catcode`\@=11
\newif\ifboxended
\def\centervbox#1{\begingroup\global\setbox\@ne=\box\voidb@x
  \global\boxendedfalse
  \setbox\z@=\copy#1\relax\docentervbox}
\def\docentervbox{%
  \setbox\z@=\vbox{\unvbox\z@ 
    \ifcase\lastnodetype
% char node (can't remove)
    \or
% hlist node
    \setbox\tw@=\lastbox
    \def\next{%
      \global\setbox\@ne=\vbox{
        \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\tw@\hfil}\unvbox\@ne}}%
    \or
% vlist node
    \setbox\tw@=\lastbox
    \def\next{%
      \global\setbox\@ne=\vbox{
        \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\tw@\hfil}\unvbox\@ne}}%
    \or
% rule node (can't remove)
    \or
% ins node (can't remove)
    \or
% mark node (can't remove)
    \or
% adjust node (can't remove)
    \or
% ligature node (can't happen)
    \or
% disc node (can't happen)
    \or
% whatsit node (can't remove)
    \or
% math node (can't remove)
    \or
% glue node
    \skip@=\lastskip\unskip
    \def\next{\global\setbox\@ne=\vbox{\vskip\skip@\unvbox\@ne}}%
    \or
% kern node
    \dimen@=\lastkern\unkern
    \def\next{\global\setbox\@ne=\vbox{\kern\dimen@\unvbox\@ne}}%
    \or
% penalty node
    \count@=\lastpenalty\unpenalty
    \def\next{\global\setbox\@ne=\vbox{\penalty\count@\unvbox\@ne}}%
    \or
% unset node (can't happen)
    \or
% math mode node (can't remove)
    \else
% empty list
    \def\next{\global\boxendedtrue}
    \fi
    \next}
  \ifboxended
    \def\next{\unvbox\@ne\endgroup}
  \else
    \let\next\docentervbox
  \fi
  \next}
\catcode`\@=12
```

The list of node types can be found in the documentation of e-TeX (`texdoc etex`). The special case -1 is when the list is empty, which we use to end the recursion.

Comment: Awesome! This works like a charm! I'll share my motivations as soon as I clean up my code a bit.

Comment: Give a look at the second method.

Comment: Here is the motivation https://gist.github.com/1099872 (Compile it for explainations). And I think I'm forced to stick with the first method. Thanks again!

Comment: It is possible to add the `\count@=\lastpenalty\unpenalty` trick to your `\centervbox` macro! Seems to work fine. Also, is `\ht0=0` really equivalent to "`\box0` is empty"?

Comment: One should cycle through skips and penalties, in order to remove them. There is e-TeX code that can examine the last node type so as to take appropriate actions: `\ifcase\lastnodetype...\fi`. I'll try to supply the necessary macros. The box never becomes really void, but there's the special type for `\lastnodetype` when the list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

`\halign` is plain tex coding, so adding glue to the right and left of each element is best done in the plain style.  thus

```
\vbox{
  \halign{\quad\hfil#&\quad\hfil#\hfil\quad&#\hfil\quad\cr
  aa & b & cc\cr
  d & eee & f\cr}
}
```

would do the job; replace `\quad` by any appropriate fixed glue amount. it need not be the same amount in all positions.  traditionally, half of the glue is put in on either side of the `&`, but it should work as well all in one place since it looks like you want the first column right-aligned, the second column centered, and the third column left-aligned.

Comment: Thanks, sorry if my question was unclear, the main point was to break the top level vbox so the contents can be split across pages.