# Measure total glue in a box

Tags: tex-core, boxes

Someone gives me a box, and my goal is to know as much as possible about the amount of glue inside that box.  I can assume that the box is not huge, but it may contain arbitrary stuff (so I cannot deconstruct the box using `\unskip` and friends).

For definiteness, say that the box `\mybox` was defined with `\newbox\mybox` then constructed using `\setbox\mybox\hbox to 50pt{a b c}`.  To get the natural width of the box's contents, I can do `\setbox0\hbox{\unhcopy\mybox}\showthe\wd0` (and I'll get `21.66669pt`).

To know if the box contains infinite stretch I can typeset it inside a box of width `\maxdimen` and check for the badness (well, that's not entirely fool-proof, but should be ok), and similarly for infinite shrink.

What I'd be interested in is to know the stretch or shrink in the finite case.  My feeling is that it should be possible to extract that by checking the `\badness` after `\setbox0\hbox spread \somedim{\unhcopy\mybox}` with various `\somedim`.  Is this correct?  Is there a more efficient approach?

Comment: You know s>0 (spread) and b<10000 (badness) and you need to calculate f (total stretch in the box). This can be done by f = root 3 of {100 s^3 \over b}. I mean that you are specialist for such type of calculations in TeX...

Comment: I suppose using \showbox and reading a copy of the log (with TeX) is cheating?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Given the goal, which would be to have a more clever method for math layout (where e.g., subscripts do not have to take their natural width), yes, reading the log is cheating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: one can find the natural width of the box, the exact amount of stretch if it is finite (otherwise one can only say "it's infinite"), and similarly the exact amount of shrink if it is finite.

Let us assume for definiteness that `\mybox` is a horizontal box such as

```
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox\hbox spread 5pt{Some text perhaps.}
```

To find its natural width, do `\setbox0\hbox{\unhcopy\mybox}`: then the
answer is the width `\wd0` of box 0.

We can only probe the amount of glue stretch or shrink by setting the
box with a width different from its natural width, and testing the
`\badness`.  Setting the box to a width larger than its natural width
probes the stretch component, and setting it to a width smaller than its
natural width probes the shrink component.  In both cases, if the
corresponding component (stretch for larger widths, shrink for smaller
widths) is infinite then the `\badness` will be zero, telling us nothing
about the value or sign of that infinite component.  I see no other way
to probe such infinite values, so let's focus on the finite case.

The general formula for the badness is quite complicated: it involves in
some cases the combination `100(t/s)^3` where `t` is the difference
between the natural width of the box and the width that was asked for,
and `s` is the amount of stretch (or shrink, if the box was squeezed).
Fortunately, we can go by with only a very simple case.  Our basic
construction for testing the amount of stretch is `\setbox0\hbox spread
1sp{\unhcopy\mybox\hskip 0pt plus -\stest}` where `\stest` is a
dimension that we will vary.  The amount of stretch in this box is the
amount in `\mybox`, minus `\stest`.  If that is positive, then the box
can stretch, and the `\badness` is not too big (as it turns out, 100 or
less).  Otherwise, the box is underfull, as it cannot stretch even by
`1sp`, and the `\badness` is 10000 (when testing the shrink, we get
overfull boxes with a `\badness` of 1000000).  We thus have a simple way
to test whether the amount of stretch in `\mybox` is `>\stest` or
`<=\stest` for any dimension `\stest`.  The task is thus reduced to a
dichotomy.

```
\hbadness=1000000
\hfuzz=\maxdimen
\newdimen\stest
\newdimen\smin
\newdimen\smax
\def\find#1#2#3{%
  \smin = -\maxdimen
  \smax = \maxdimen
  \loop
    \stest = \smin
    \advance \stest by \smax
    \divide \stest by 2 % now \stest=(\smin+\smax)/2 truncated to 0
    \ifdim \stest = \smax
      \advance \stest by -1sp % ensure that \smin<=\stest<\smax.
    \fi
    \setbox 0 = \hbox spread #2 1sp {%
      \unhcopy\mybox
      \hskip 0pt #3-\stest
    }%
    \ifnum \badness > 100 % (shrink/stretch in \mybox) <= \stest
      \smax = \stest
    \else
      \smin = \stest
      \advance \smin by 1sp
      % since ">\stest" implies ">=\stest+1sp"
    \fi
    % In both cases, the interval [\smin,\smax] becomes smaller.
  \ifdim\smin<\smax
  \repeat
  \ifdim\smin>\smax\BOOM\fi% cannot happen, I think
  \message{^^JThe #1 is
    \ifdim\smin=\maxdimen infinite\else\the\smin\fi.}% (\smin=\smax)
}
\setbox0\hbox{\unhcopy\mybox}
\message{^^JThe natural width is \the\wd0 .}
\find{stretch}{}{plus}
\find{shrink}{-}{minus}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `\mybox` is a vbox, then we can solve the problem almost entirely by saving the current page, dumping the box contents on the main vertical list, accumulating `\pagestretch` and friends inside an output routine, and then restoring the current page.

This method can not be used to measure infinitely shrinkable glue, because TeX does not allow such glue on the main vertical list. As Bruno pointed out, you could at least check if the box contains infinitely shrinkable glue by unboxing it in a vbox of height `-\maxdimen` and checking the `\badness`.

```tex
\newbox\savedpage
\newdimen\savedprevdepth
\newdimen\stretch
\newdimen\filstretch
\newdimen\fillstretch
\newdimen\filllstretch
\newdimen\shrink
\def\savepage{%
    \savedprevdepth=\prevdepth
    {\output={\global\setbox\savedpage=\box255}%
    \holdinginserts=1 \eject}}
\def\restorepage{\unvbox\savedpage \prevdepth=\savedprevdepth}
\def\findglue{%
    \savepage
    \stretch=0pt
    \filstretch=0pt
    \fillstretch=0pt
    \filllstretch=0pt
    \shrink=0pt
    \begingroup
        \output={%
            \global\advance\stretch\pagestretch
            \global\advance\filstretch\pagefilstretch
            \global\advance\fillstretch\pagefillstretch
            \global\advance\filllstretch\pagefilllstretch
            \global\advance\shrink\pageshrink
            \setbox0=\box255
            \null % Keep discardables after page break.
        }%
        \vsize=\maxdimen
        \topskip=0pt
        \null % Keep discardables at top of mybox.
        \unvcopy\mybox
        \eject
        \output={\setbox0=\box255}%
        \eject % Remove the \null and \penalty10000 remaining on the page.
    \endgroup
    \restorepage}

% Only needed for the print-out
{\catcode`\p=12 \catcode`\t=12 \gdef\\#1pt{#1}}
\def\decimal{\expandafter\\\the}

\setbox0=\vbox{\boxmaxdepth=0pt \unvcopy\mybox}
\findglue
Height-plus-depth of box:
\the\ht0\ 
plus \the\stretch\ 
plus \decimal\filstretch fil
plus \decimal\fillstretch fill
plus \decimal\filllstretch filll
minus \the\shrink
```

The `\savepage` and `\restorepage` macros assume that you have not been manually touching `\pagegoal`, `\pagetotal`, etc., and that `\topskip` has not changed since the saved page was started. If this is not the case, you should save and restore those quantities in addition to the page contents.