# Insert a special character at each end of line in a paragraph

Tags: tables, formatting, paragraphs

I would like to add a character (e.g. `$\hookleftarrow$`) at the end of each line in a paragraph, in particular in a `tabular` cell, only if the paragraph has more than one line.

How can this be coded?

Comment: Possibly related: [How to put > before lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248944).

Comment: see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188797/obtain-badness-or-glue-adjustment-for-each-line

Answer (score 1):

Using the link provided by @GustavoMezzetti I've solved my question. The modified code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\ppp}[1]{%
 \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}{%
  #1
  \par
  \count0=\prevgraf
  \count2=\prevgraf
  \loop
   \ifnum\count0=\count2\else\mbox{}\hfill\rlap{\hspace*{0.1em}$\hookleftarrow$}\fi
   \vskip-2\baselineskip
   \advance\count0 -1
   \ifnum\count0 > 0
  \repeat
  \kern\count2\baselineskip\mbox{}%
  \strut}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\ppp{\blindtext}

\noindent\ppp{one line only}
\end{document}
```

Thank @GustavoMezzetti and @touhami. The post linked by @touhami is very interesting.