# count the newlines in title

Tags: line-breaking, counters

I am trying to automatically adjust the title page to get a pleasing result independent of the title size. This means that I have to count the number of line breaks in an argument.

My MWE (not very pleasing to make it really minimal)

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\maketitlepage}[1]{% the title page is generated here
  \edef\caesar@titlespace{\the\dimexpr 210pt - 15pt * #1 \relax}% calculate the necessary space
  \cleardoublepage%
  \begingroup%
  {%
  \noindent\LARGE\@author\par
  \vfill%
  \noindent\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont\@title\par
  \vfill%
  \vspace{\caesar@titlespace}%
  \Large\noindent\publisher\par
  }%
  \endgroup%
  \clearpage%
}

\makeatother

\title{This is\\a title}
\author{John Doe}
\newcommand{\publisher}{Some University}

\begin{document}
\maketitlepage{2} % two lines
\title{This is\\new\\a title}
\maketitlepage{3} % three lines

\end{document}
```

Please note that I manually count the lines and provide `\maketitlepage` the extra argument. I cannot figure out how to calculate it automatically.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier (and more logical) to measure the total height of the title? This is surely possible using `\sbox`, `\vbox` and `\ht`. As well, it would be bullet-proof for the case when a normal linebreak appears.

Comment: Yes, that would probably be even better. Could you give a short answer how to achieve that?

Comment: I did measuring first and then divided by baselinskip to get a rought linecount but decided to do the loop counting lines instead exactly:-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{aaa\\b\\bb}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\vbox{\noindent\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont\@title\par
\count@\z@
\loop
\unskip\unpenalty\unskip\unpenalty\unskip
\setbox0\lastbox
\ifvoid0
\xdef\numlines{\the\count@}%
\else
\advance\count@\@ne
\repeat}

\show\numlines
\stop
```

this leaves the number of lines in `\numlines` :

```
> \numlines=macro:
->3.
l.20 \show\numlines
```

---

If instead you just want to go by the height of the title just do something like the following instead:

```
\setbox0\vbox{\noindent\fontsize{30}{38}\selectfont\@title}

\ifdim\ht0> 70pt .... \else ... \fi
```

Comment: I have no idea how `\lastbox` works. Is the key here to use `\unskip\unpenalty\unskip\unpenalty\unskip` (for whatever reason) until `\lastbox` becomes void? Would you elaborate on the contents inside `\loop`...`\repeat`?

Comment: @Werner \lastbox removes the last item from the current list if it was a box (and in this case stores it in box register 0) the unskip and unpenalty through away any baseline glue or inter-line penaltites. With a bit of luck there are no \special or \mark nodes  so if each iteration of the loop \lastbox should take off a line of text until there is no line left when it will be void.

Comment: @Werner A more careful loop that checks for all the possible node types with comments and better explanation in egreg's answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28064/how-to-display-only-certain-lines-of-a-paragraph/28070#28070

Comment: Your solution got a performance hit (unfortunately down) in the latest TeXLive using LuaLaTeX. Does anyone know why this is or even how to achieve the same using some (faster?!) lua code?

Comment: @Andy does it? That's bizarre as it's classic tex code that would have run in tex82, I'm surprised that bit of luatex changed much. If it's reproducible you could try raising it on the luatex support list. I expect it can't be answered without the sources open in a debugger:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I apologize, I did not use my own MWE, but the actual document. It turned out to be the new `microtype`-package in combination with LuaLaTeX. I will try to track it down further...