# Access node contents in style and get number of lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

**EDIT**: I'd like to set the `yshift` of a node to be some factor of the number of lines in the node's contents. In trying to determine the number of lines, I originally wrote the question below.

**EDIT** A partial solution, based on the answer of Schrödinger's cat, is below with figure and code. It is not fully automated, specifying boxes and the use of `\pgftruncatemacro` before each node is not desirable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=6]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}

\begin{document}

\newbox\mybox\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\hbox{foo}\hbox{bar}\hbox{bazzy}}
\newbox\myboxb\setbox\myboxb=\vbox{\hbox{\ttfamily abc\#xyz}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  card/.style={
    draw,
    dashed,
    anchor=base west,
    inner sep=0,
    append after command={[/utils/exec=\let\mytikzlastnode\tikzlastnode]
      node [
      below=5mm of \tikzlastnode.base east,
      anchor=base east,
      font=\scriptsize,
      inner sep=0
      ] (mynode) {#1}
      node [draw,fit={(\mytikzlastnode) (mynode.base east)}] {}
    },
  }
  ]

  \draw (-1,0) -- (5,0);

  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myn}{(\dp\mybox+\ht\mybox+2pt)/11.5pt}\myn
  \node [card=num1,yshift=-(\myn-1)*\baselineskip] (A) {\box\mybox};

  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myn}{(\dp\myboxb+\ht\myboxb+2pt)/11.5pt}\myn
  \node [card=c2,right=1cm of A,yshift=-(\myn-1)*\baselineskip] (B) {\box\myboxb};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Original question**:
I'd like to attach the number of lines in a node's contents as an "auxiliary" node, MWE below.

I have a candidate solution to count the number of lines of something from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/317724/47128), but I cannot parse the code well enough to untangle that solution from `\title`. I have not been able to find a way to access the node contents from the `style`.

```
\documentclass[margin=6]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  card/.style={
    draw,
    dashed,
    inner sep=0,
    append after command={
      \pgfextra{
        \node [
        below=5mm of \tikzlastnode.base east,
        anchor=base east,
        font=\scriptsize,
        inner sep=0
        ] (mynode) {????}; % get node contents and count lines
        \node [draw,fit={(\tikzlastnode) (mynode.base east)}] {};
      }
    }
  }
  ]

  \node [card] (C) {foobar\\baz};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a 100% fool proof way of measuring the number of lines with Ti*k*Z. What if you have, say, a large integral sign? However, for normal lines you could just measure the height and infer the number from this height. BTW, do *not* use `\pgfextra` in paths.

```
\documentclass[margin=6]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  card/.style={align=center,
    draw,
    dashed,
    inner sep=0,
    append after command={[/utils/exec=\let\mytikzlastnode\tikzlastnode]
    let \p1=($(\mytikzlastnode.north)-(\mytikzlastnode.south)$) in 
     node [
        below=5mm of \tikzlastnode.base east,
        anchor=base east,
        font=\scriptsize,
        inner sep=0
        ] (mynode) {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myn}{(\y1+5pt)/11.5pt}\myn} % get node contents and count lines
        node [draw,fit={(\mytikzlastnode) (mynode.base east)}] {}
    }
  }
  ]

  \draw node [card] (A) {foobar};

  \draw (3,0) node [card] (B) {foobar\\baz};

  \draw (6,0) node [card] (C) {foobar\\baz\\blub};

  \draw (9,0) node [card] (D) {foobar\\baz\\blub\\pft};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is clever. I dumbed down my MWE a little too far from what I actually want to achieve, I guess. I really want to be able to align these `card` objects by the baseline of the first line of text, so what I was thinking was to anchor a new object at `base` (baseline of the last line), compute the number of lines less 1, multiply times `\baselineskip`, then set the result as the `yshift` in the node style. I'm still learning about `append after...`, `execute after...` etc. Is it possible to do the calculation you provided, but set the result as `yshift` of the initial node?