# \foreach \i in {1,...,\pgfmathresult} not working

Tags: foreach, pgfmath

After calculating \pgfmathresult and turning the output as an integer:

```
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
```

Which for example is 10, I want to iterate instead of

```
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{%
    some iteration
    }
```

,with something like this

```
\foreach \i in {1,...,\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}{%
some iteration
}
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work. How can I approach this, any ideas?

THX a lot!

Comment: Maybe better use `\pgfmathparse{int(<your calculation>)}` and then `\foreach \i in {1,...,\pgfmathresult}{` ...

Comment: The most straight-forward way is probably `\foreach[parse=true] \i in {1, ..., int(<your calculation>)}` but we'd need to know more about your actual calculation to figure out what's best. `\pgfmathprintnumber` certainly won't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jasper, your code works in my case!

Comment: Thanks also to you, Qrrbrbirlbel!
The calculation is the "number of lines in a text", which is from osjerick in this post:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317713/count-lines-in-a-block-of-text

So basically, i wantet to calculate first the number of lines in a paragraph, and then with this integer, iterating through some stuff.